# Vector of Card classes for Uno

Tags: c++

I'm currently in the process of making Uno for a programming project. One part requires that I make the deck of 108 cards, where Card is its own class with a `char color` and an `std::string value`, the values of which I get from a file. I currently am just creating all 108 cards individually and then using `push_back` to put them in the cards vector. Is there any way to more efficiently make the cards and put them into the vector? Currently it takes up 324 lines

Draw.cpp

```
#include "Pile.h"
#include "Draw.h"
#include "Card.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

Draw::Draw(const std::string FILENAME)
{
    std::ifstream inFile;

    inFile.open(FILENAME);

    if (inFile)
    {
        char newColor;
        std::string newValue;
        inFile >> newColor >> newValue;
        Card card1(newColor, newValue);
        this->cards.push_back(card1);
        inFile >> newColor >> newValue;
        Card card2(newColor, newValue);
        this->cards.push_back(card2);
        ...
        inFile >> newColor >> newValue;
        Card card107(newColor, newValue);
        this->cards.push_back(card107);
        inFile >> newColor >> newValue;
        Card card108(newColor, newValue);
        this->cards.push_back(card108);
    }
    else
    {
    std::cout << "ERROR:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The file " << FILENAME << " does not exist." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The deck cannot be created." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ThomasSablik That was the only answer at the time and the comments on it fixed what was wrong with it so I just accepted it the answer. Since there are other ones now I made one that was more correct the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as reading from a file and instantiating objects line by line goes, the code you’ve written is correct. However if I’m correct in assuming your goal is to make the code readable/more concise, a for loop would go a long way.

For loops are code blocks that will automatically increment a counter variable for you until a certain condition is hit. In this case, it might look something like this:

```
int i;

for(i = 0; i < 108; i++) {
    char newColor;
    std::string newValue;
    inFile >> newColor >> newValue;
    Card card(newColor, newValue);
    this->cards.push_back(card);
}
```

Note that this will fail (as will your other implementation) if the input file has any missing values. You can check for this by adding conditionals like this:

```
if(!(inFile >> newColor >> newValue)) {
    break;
}
else {
   this->cards.push_back(card);
}
```

Comment: IMO always test for a positive instead of a negative. It's easier to read and understand. The else shouldn't ever be the expected correct behavior case. Since you're in a loop you don't need the else at all. You'll get there because you didn't break.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for` loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 108; i++) {
    char newColor;
    std::string newValue;
    inFile >> newColor >> newValue;
    Card card(newColor, newValue);
    this->cards.push_back(card);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
while (inFile)
{
    char newColor;
    std::string newValue;
    inFile >> newColor >> newValue;
    Card card(newColor, newValue);
    this->cards.push_back(card);
}
```

is all you need

Comment: This code have problem like [c - Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: You should add a check after `inFile >> newColor >> newValue;`, e.g. `if (!inFile) break;`

Comment: I'd make the loop based on a successful read to avoid adding a bogus card at the end if the read fails.. `while (inFile >> newColor >> newValue) { ... }`

Comment: Oh is that really it? I was going to do that but I thought it wouldn't work. Looking at it now I see where my mistaken thinking was. Thanks!